# Value in textbox disappears when I click the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a textbox where in user selects a value and soon as I press the submit button the value disappears.

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="patient in $ctrl.patient | filter:$ctrl.mrd">
     <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label " for="company">Choose the required data</label>
            <div>
                <select id="selectSensor" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select sensor type</option>
                </select>
                <select id="selectTime" class="form-control">
                    <option>Select timestamp</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <a class="btn btn-success" onClick='checkEntry();'
                   href=".#!/patients/{{ patient[0] }}/plot/#"
                   role="button">Show</a>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

For here I am entering the value for Sensor type and then it moves to the onClick(). When I click Show, the value I gave for the Sensor type disappears.

The function is given below for checkEntry()

```
 function checkEntry() {
    typeSelected = $("#selectSensor").val();
    timeSelected = $("#selectTime").val();
    if (timeSelected != "" && (typeSelected != ""))
        idValue = 4;
}
```

Comment: The form being submitted. Please stop

Comment: Dollars to doughnuts, you're submitting the actual form and reloading the page

Comment: Use a click handler and `event.preventDefault`, see https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Yeah! The form is being submitted but the value disappears, I want to see the value. In that case what should I do ?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Using the event.preventDefault function will it prevent the page from refreshing. I tried using the function inside the onclick function but didn't show any change.

Comment: If you just added that in the function you have, you're probably getting the error `event is undefined`. You need to use an event handler as shown on that page. For example, add the class `do-a-thing` to your button then do this `$( ".do-a-thing" ).click(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault(); 
  // your code here
});`

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is trying to execute the `href` before `onclick` handler. In this snippet i replace the `href` value with some other value and it will execute after the onclick function.So the onclick function will first execute followed by the href, else you can add the href navigation inside the onclick function

```js
function checkEntry(e) {
 
  typeSelected = $("#selectSensor").val();
  console.log('1')
  timeSelected = $("#selectTime").val();
  if (timeSelected != "" && (typeSelected != ""))
    idValue = 4;
return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel-body" ng-repeat="patient in $ctrl.patient | filter:$ctrl.mrd">


  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label " for="company">Choose the required data</label>
      <div>
        <select id="selectSensor" class="form-control">
                                <option>Select sensor type</option>
                            </select>
        <select id="selectTime" class="form-control">
                                <option>Select timestamp</option>
                            </select>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">

        <a class="btn btn-success" onClick='checkEntry();' href="www.google.com" role="button">Show</a>
     </div>
  </div>
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: How can I make the onclick function execute before the href ?